# Monospace font and custom font (Marshmallow)

Tags: java, android, xml, fonts

I recently made an RPG with ASCII-arts and since android 5.0 there arts are messed up.

I use a custom font to display it, defined with this :

```
Typeface face= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/courier.ttf");
    etiqPlateau.setTypeface(face);
```

I used the android:fontFamily="monospace" setting in the xml but it looks like the TypeFace defined in java code overrides the xml setting. Is it possible to define the attributes of a typeface in xml or at least define the use of monospaced font in 5.0+ ? Help!

[In Android 4.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7th1Z.png) (Picture)

[In Android 6.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OV0Qw.png) (Picture)

EDIT -- 
Even when I use the android:fontfamily on XML without setting up a typeface, android 5.0+ messes up the monospace font.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this

```
public static class FontCache {

    private static HashMap<String, Typeface> fontCache = new HashMap<>();

    public static Typeface getTypeface(String fontname, Context context) {
        Typeface typeface = fontCache.get(fontname);

        if (typeface == null) {
            try {
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontname);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }

            fontCache.put(fontname, typeface);
        }

        return typeface;
    }
}
```

> Typeface customFont = FontCache.getTypeface("your custom downloaded
>   font.ttf", clContext);

```
code snippet:
Typeface customFont = FontCache.getTypeface("chyga.ttf", clContext);
yourTextView.setTypeface(customFont);
```